# Text from Textbox in a User Control

Tags: winforms, c#-4.0

I got a combobox, where the User can choose one out of different Items,

based on the Selected Item I am showing a UserControl with various Labels and Textfields.

How can I get the values from the Textfield in my User Control?

Comment: you can create public properties in your user control to expose the texfield value. You can share some your code here. some pointers http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms972975.aspx & http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/20550/C-Event-Implementation-Fundamentals-Best-Practices

Comment: @coderhawk answer posted ;) I figured it out in the moment in that you posted your comment. Thank You!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a bit  Try and Error the solution for me is to create a getter in the User Control and then acces it via the UserControls Object.

```
     public string Text
     {
     get { return sampletextbox.Text; }

     }
```

---

```
     SampleControl sample = new SampleControl();
```

---

```
     string samplestring = sample.Text;
```